# Insert field headers into CSV using batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I would like to insert field headers to an CSV file using `.bat`.

The CSV file without field headers looks as below:

> ```
> "Accounting",…
> "Billing",…
> "IT",…
> ```

After the `.bat` file has run, the file should have the field header "Team" added to it as shown below:

> ```
> "Team",…
> "Accounting",…
> "Billing",…
> "IT",…
> ```

I have already tried the following code but this overwrites the entire file with just the field header, hence the other information is missing:

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Define folder to scan, and output file for CSV results
set BaseDir=c:\temp
set OutputFile=TEST.csv

(
  rem Write column headers to output file
  echo Doc Name,Revision Number,File Type,Modified Date,File Path

  rem Process all files in all folders under base folder
  for /f "tokens=*" %%I in ('dir /s/b/a-d "%BaseDir%"') do (

    rem Write file data to output file
    echo "%%~nI","","%%~xI",%%~tI,"%%~dpI"

  )

)> "%OutputFile%"

rem Open output CSV file in Excel for analysis
start excel "%OutputFile%"
```

Could someone assist me with this?

Comment: Just use the TYPE command https://ss64.com/nt/type.html along with echo redirection https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: I suggest a batch file with just following three command lines after `@echo off`. The first one is `echo Doc Name,Revision Number,File Type,Modified Date,File Path>"%TEMP%\Header.tmp"` which writes the header line into a temporary file. The second one is `for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Temp\*.csv" /A-D /B 2^>nul') do copy /B "%TEMP%\Header.tmp" + "C:\Temp\%%I" "C:\Temp\%%~nI_tmp%%~xI" >nul & move /Y "C:\Temp\%%~nI_tmp%%~xI" "C:\Temp\%%I" & start "" excel.exe "C:\Temp\%%I"` to concatenate temporary header file with CSV file and start Excel with resulting file.

Comment: The third one is `del "%TEMP%\Header.tmp"` to delete the temporary header file.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a tmp file and concatenate with the **`CSV`** file currently in the loop, then merge and delete tmp file ... accordelly with **[@Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)** comments...

---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d "c:\temp" && for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%I in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "." *.csv')do (
set "_f=%%~dpI!random!._tmp" & (echo[Doc Name,Revision Number,File Type,Modified Date,File Path 
echo["%%~nI","","%%~xI","%%~tI","%%~dpI" && type "%%~fI" ) >"!_f!" && move /y "!_f!" "%%~dpnxI"
start "" excel "%%~fI" && >nul del /q /v "!_f!" )

endlocal && popd && goto :EOF
```

---

- Same code in conventional formating

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

cd /d "c:\temp"

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%I in ('%__APPDIR__%where.exe /r "." *.csv')do (
      set "_f=%%~dpI!random!._tmp" && (
      echo[Doc Name,Revision Number,File Type,Modified Date,File Path 
      echo["%%~nI","","%%~xI","%%~tI","%%~dpI"
      type "%%~fI" 
      ) >"!_f!" && move /y "!_f!" "%%~dpnxI"
      start "" excel "%%~fI" 
      >nul del /q /v "!_f!"
      )
endlocal && popd && goto :EOF
```

---